# OpenDaylight AbstractBindingAwareConsumer is deprecated

Tags: opendaylight, sdn

I am writing a plugin for OpenDaylight and I saw that in Helium release the AbstractBindingAwareConsumer or AbstractBindingAwareProducer are deprecated.

Does someone know why is this and what should I use instead ?

Thank you